# Lists inside ams proofs

Tags: lists, amsart

I'm using amsart.  I'm really annoyed that when I put a list inside a proof (and use a mark for the list), it is indented more than it should be.  This is probably because the proof environment is implemented as a trivlist, and sublists often get more indentation.

But the question is what do I do about it?  I don't want to re-implement the proof environment... I may not get the details exactly the same.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

\begin{list}{Mark}{}
\item Hi
\end{list}

\begin{proof}\
\begin{list}{Mark}{}
\item Hi
\end{list}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You know, I never even noticed this.  I guess I don't ever use lists *outside* proofs.  +1 for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine the `\leftmargin` length:

```
\begin{proof}\mbox{}
\begin{list}{Mark}{\setlength\leftmargin{1.2em}}
\item Hi
\end{list}
\end{proof}
```

Using the `enumitem` package, you can define your own customized list that will behave consistently throughout the document:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[mylist]{label=\arabic*}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
  \item Hi
\end{mylist}

\begin{proof}\mbox{}
\begin{mylist}
  \item Hi
\end{mylist}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (Sorry; I wrote something incorrect because I'd misread the answer, and although I can edit my comment I can't seem to totally delete it.  Please just ignore me...)

Comment: This solution is problematic because the number, 1.2em, depends on the size of the "Mark" characters.  It also depends on whether or not you're in a proof.  So it's not like I can just redefine the list environment and everything will work out.

Comment: @sam: see my updated answer.

Comment: This totally works.  Thanks!!  Let me wait another day to see if anyone finds a short, non-package solution before accepting this one.

Comment: I should mention that the ordinary "enumerate" environment works too.  It's only the general "list" that I think has the problem.

Answer (score 2):

when using `amsthm`, if you want the list to begin on a new line, then follow the `\begin` command for the proof environment by `\leavevmode`.

if instead you want to start the list on the same line as the heading, this is the recommended way, adjusting the space between the heading and the first item:

```
\begin{proof}[<optional modifier>]
\hangindent\leftmargini
\textup{(1)}\hskip\labelsep First item. Provide a long text
  to show what happens when there is more than one line.
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{1}
\item Second
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
```

this works as well with any theorem-class object.

since this is basically a kludge, the topic is on the list of things to be considered the next time an upgrade is undertaken.

Comment: This seems to be answering a different question---that of whether to start lists on the same line as an environment or the next, and how to do it.  My question concerned lists anywhere inside a proof (and their behavior being different from outside).

Comment: @sam -- thanks for the clarification.  you're correct that the answer addresses lists beginning a proof environment.  however, i was unaware that lists further inside the environment behaved any differently than they do outside, and i've looked at a lot of them.  please send a minimal working example to `tech-support@ams.org`; we will take a look and enter a bug report as appropriate.

Comment: Oh, cool.  There's a working example in the original question; I'll send it to ams too.