# Why don't my hyperref links work with amsart?

Tags: hyperref, amsart

When I process the file below either with pdflatex, or with latex and then dvipdf, the link on page 1 of the resulting PDF file does not take me to Lemma 1 as expected.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

See Lemma~\ref{testlemma} below.
\pagebreak

\begin{lem}\label{testlemma}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Testing!
  \end{enumerate}
\end{lem}

\end{document}
```

When I use pdflatex then I get a warning:

```
pdfTeX warning (dest): name
{lem.1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

If I replace `\documentclass{amsart}` with `\documentclass{article}` then the link works as expected.

How can I fix this test file to get working hyperref links in PDF files with `amsart`?

I am using pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian).

Comment: The same happens if the class is `article` and `amsthm` is loaded before `hyperref`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for the reference counter of a theorem-class environment to be properly accessed
by a `\label`, something has to follow the `\begin{<`*environment*`>}` in horizontal mode.
since the next thing in this example is `\begin{enumerate}`, horizontal mode is never
entered, and the label is lost.  (i'm not sure exactly *how* it gets lost, but that's
the net effect.)

there are various approaches to handling this situation.  all involve inserting something
in horizontal mode before starting the list.  the suggestions most often made (other than adding actual text) are `\leavevmode` or `$ $`; even a single "slash-space" will work.
however, all of these will result in the list being started on the next line rather than
being run-in.

here are two other questions that address related situations, although not the interaction
with `\label`:

- [Theorem starting with a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154854/579).
- [Theorem formatting: strange interaction with itemize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49171/579).

here's a somewhat different approach that involves entering the number of the first item manually, and starting the "real" enumeration with the second item; it's applied to a proof in this answer, but works as well with any theorem-class object.  advantage -- this allows a label intended to point to the theorem to have the correct value; disadvantage -- it may not be possible to have a cross-reference to the first item.

- [Lists inside ams proofs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21643/579)

Comment: Following this, I tried putting the `\label` command after the first `\item`. The link works, but the item number (not the lemma number) becomes the link.

Comment: @Dan - Which object do you wish to cross-reference: The entire lemma, or a specific enumerated item within the lemma? You can assign a `\label` to both the lemma and to individual enumerated items.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `\leavevmode` before the `enumerate` environment fixes the issue.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{test}\label{sec:1}

See Lemma~\ref{testlemma} or rather Lemma~\ref{testlemma2} below.

\begin{lem}
\label{testlemma}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Testing!
  \end{enumerate}
\end{lem}

\begin{lem}
\label{testlemma2}
\leavevmode
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Testing!
  \end{enumerate}
\end{lem}

\begin{lem}
\label{testlemma3}
\leavevmode  
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Testing!
  \end{enumerate}
\end{lem}

lemma \ref{testlemma2}

section \ref{sec:1}

lemma \ref{testlemma3}

reference to lemma \ref{testlemma} does not work.
\end{document}
```

Comment: or any text which will start paragraph mode.